# Problems repainting in a JPanel Runnable

Tags: java, repaint, paintcomponent

I am writing a program that will play a song and have a JPanel displaying images during it. The song plays fine, the first image is drawn (I assume from the initial call to paintComponent) but somehow the repaint() doesn't seem to be getting called. I could really use an extra set of eyes. I have the code below for the JPanel class that will be displaying the images. Thanks so much!

```
class pictures extends JPanel implements Runnable {
private ImageIcon images[];
private Thread imagerunner;
private int currentImage;

pictures() {
    super();
    imagerunner = new Thread(this);
    images = new ImageIcon[6];
    imagerunner = new Thread(this);
    images[0] = new ImageIcon("pic1.jpg");
    images[1] = new ImageIcon("pic2.jpg");
    images[2] = new ImageIcon("pic3.jpg");
    images[3] = new ImageIcon("pic4.jpg");
    images[4] = new ImageIcon("pic5.jpg");
    images[5] = new ImageIcon("pic6.jpg");
    currentImage = 0;
}

public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("starting pics");
    while( i < 100 ) {
        System.out.println("about to repaint()");
        this.repaint();
        System.out.println( "image: " + currentImage );
        waiting( 2000 );
        currentImage++;
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent( g );
    System.out.println("repainting");
    images[ currentImage ].paintIcon(this,g,0,0);
}

public static void waiting (int n) {
    long t0, t1;
    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    while (t1 - t0 < n);
}
}
```

Comment: how do you call this class's code?  Where do you call start() on your Thread?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  BTW - what do you expect to happen when the `currentImage` counter reaches 6?

Answer (score 0):

1. You never start the thread `imagerunner`.
2. It is assigned twice (for no reason).
3. You can't modify GUI from another thread. Use [Swing utilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `waiting()` method seems to be blocking the EDT.  It would be better to use a Swing `Timer` to schedule the updates.

Comment: I'm not so sure that it's blocking the EDT since it *seems* to be called in a separate thread (the Runnable run method), but we never do get to see how he starts up the Thread, so it's hard to say if he does that right.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels:  You may be correct, I'll give it some extra thought once the OP posts an SSCCE.

Comment: You are right! Java makes my head hurt, and I'm not sure exactly why you are right but changing it to a Timer fixed the problem. However, I was hoping to have variable length delays and timer has a fixed delay. Is there any way to make it variable? For now I'm just going to set the delay short and have images repeat, but I imagine there is probably a more elagant solution. *edit: oh and by the way, THANK YOU.

Comment: @John M - don't forget to "accept" an answer when the suggestions solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the following:

1) Actually create an instance to run.
2) You will need to invoke repaint() regularly in order to get your display to repaint.

Hope it helps. Cheers!